# Algorithm to solve rank k perturbation of system of equations with identity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algorithms

Let $I$ be the identity matrix of size $n \times n$, $ v_0, v_1, ... v_k$ be $k$ linearly independent vectors and $y$ be a vector. 
I want to find an algorithm solving the following equation : $ ( I + \sum_k v_kv_k^t )x = y$. 
In this case $k $ is always much lower than $n$.

My first approach was to compute $ ( I + \sum_k v_kv_k^T )$ then solve the equation, wich gives an algorithm in $O(n^3+kn^2)$.

Using algorithm 1 from [there](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042705001032). I get better results with an algorithm in $O(nk^2)$ (much better since $k < n$ ).

But I would like to use the fact that the perturbed matrix is the identity and that the perturbations are symmetric, All other algorithms I found were slower ($O(n^2k)$ or $O(n^2k^2)$).

Any hints to find a faster algorithm are welcome.

Comment: If $v_k$ are orthogonal, then it is possible to solve it in $O(nk)$

Comment: They are not orthogonal, but how could you do this if they were ?

Comment: If you multiply the relation by $v_s^t$ you get $v_s^tx + \|v_s\|^2(v_s^tx) = v_s^ty$, so you find all $v_s^tx$ in $O(nk)$, and then, again $x = y - \sum v_k(v_k^tx)$ that is again $O(nk)$